# Issues running a custom PIT Mutation Engine Plugin

Tags: java, maven, classpath, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm writing a custom Mutation Engine for [PIT](http://pitest.org), but I'm having troubles getting PIT to find it. My guess is that I'm failing to put the package with my own engine in the right classpath when running PIT using a project. To test my engine I'm using [this code](https://bitbucket.org/hascode/pitest-tutorial.git) and I'm running PIT using the Maven plugin. In the pom.xml file I wrote the name of the custom engine and even its path inside an additionalClassPathElements tag. Nothing seems to work. PIT keeps saying it can't find the engine. Which is the best way to safely verify if it is a classpath issue? or Which is the simplest to make PIT find my package and be able to use the plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The author of the tool pointed me to the [pitest-plugin repository](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest-plugins) which seems to have exhaustive examples and explanations to build custom plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since this question was posted.
The plugin was not being found due to the way PIT was searching for external components. The issue as been solved already in version 1.2.1. Current version is 1.4.9.

Your plugin should include a `META_INF/MANIFEST.MF` declaring the following fields: `Implementation-Vendor-Id` and `Implementation-Title`. In a Maven Project, the `groupId` would go to the former and `artifactId` to the latter, so you don't really have to do anything special.

Originally, PIT used `Implementation-Vendor` which, by default would contain the organization name declared in the `pom.xml`. In my case, this value was not the same as the `groupId` and therefore PIT was not able to find the plugin.

As said in the comments the [pitest-plugin repository](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest-plugins) provides great examples on how to create your own plugins. [pitest-descartes](https://github.com/STAMP-project/pitest-descartes) and [pitest-evosuite-plugin](https://github.com/STAMP-project/pitest-evosuite-plugin) are other two examples that might be helpful as well.